# Change element position when hidden inside a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to two `GroupBox`es set inside a `StackPanel` with vertical orientation and a `CheckBox` which hides one of those group boxes in both states (checked and unchecked). The thing is that I want to have the visible `GroupBox` shown at the same position.

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="GroupBox 1" Checked="checkBox_Checked" Unchecked="checkBox_Unchecked"/>
            <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="GroupBox" Height="163">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label 1" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Label 2" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Label 3" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox1" Header="GroupBox 1">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label x:Name="label4" Content="Label 4" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label5" Content="Label 5" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label6" Content="Label 6" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox2" Header="GroupBox 2">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label x:Name="label7" Content="Label 7" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label8" Content="Label 8" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label9" Content="Label 9" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label10" Content="Label 10" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label11" Content="Label 11" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label12" Content="Label 12" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label13" Content="Label 13" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        groupBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void checkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        groupBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

result:
CheckBox UnChecked:

[image]

CheckBox Checked:

[image]

Instead of having the `groupBox1` being shown in a low position I want it to be shown at the exact same position of the first `groupBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` instead of hidden.

```
private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   groupBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   groupBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void checkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   groupBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   groupBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

See the difference between these values of the [`Visibility` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=netcore-3.1).

- `Collapsed`

  > Do not display the element, and **do not reserve** space for it in layout.
- Hidden

  > Do not display the element, **but reserve space** for the element in layout.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with a StackPanel because a StackPanel stacks the item in one direction as its name suggests. You could use a Grid to achieve what you want and just put your GroupBoxes on the same row and column.